# HTTP POST with raw body - Flutter/Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, post, dio

I am getting this error

> flutter: response body:{"Message":"The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource."}

which i am getting in post whenever i am changing the body type to text instead of json. How can i solve this.
here are the postman screenshots of both successful request and field request are given below

[image]
[image]

Here is the post method

```
Future<String> sendRequest() async {
  var jsonArray = json.encode(body);
  algo.Encrypted encrypted = Algorithm.encrypt(algorithmKey, jsonArray);
  var encryptedBosy = jsonEncode({'body': encrypted.base64});
  var response = await https.post(
    Uri.parse("$baseUrl/$paymentMethod"),
    headers: {
      "Key": key,
      "secretKey": secretKey,
    },
    body: encryptedBosy,
  );
  return response.body;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the content type header to the request.

```
headers: <String, String>{
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
},
```